# Python - Matrix assigning to all elements instead of ones specified by if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

This Python script is supposed to make a CGoL Glider, but `matrix` just outputs `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` instead of `[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` as intended.

I added a `print` statement after the `if` to display the `cell` and `block` when the `if` is flipped, and that showes the appropriate value, but the `matrix` assignment still does not work.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

matrix = [[0] * 3] * 3

def chunks(in_list, size):
    out_chunks = []
    for item in range(0, len(in_list), size):
        out_chunks.append(list(in_list[item:item + size]))
    return list(out_chunks)

for block in range(len(matrix)):
    for cell in range(len(matrix[block])):
        if chunks(range(9), 3)[block][cell] in [1, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
            print(f"Block: {block}\nCell: {cell}\n")
            matrix[block][cell] = 1
```

Comment: `[1] * 3` doesn't create 3 lists, it creates 3 references to the *same list*.

Comment: Yes, thanks, was unaware that Python could do that. `[[0] * 3 for item in range(3)]` solved the problem.